# ReferenceError: posts is not defined at eval

Tags: angularjs

I am working with Angular2,recently i am facing the error after i reinstalled the angular cli and previously it was working fine.
ReferenceError: posts is not defined at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.463.SignupComponent.ResgisterNewEmp (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:644:5), :1:1) at SignupComponent.webpackJsonp.463.SignupComponent.ResgisterNewEmp (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:644:5) at .......

```
ResgisterNewEmp(employeeCreds)
{

  this._empRegistrationService.regEmp(employeeCreds).subscribe(posts=>{

     this.result=posts;////===>(this.,result is " ", and posts is throwing error)////
     if(this.result =="201")
        {
            this._router.navigate(['Signin']);
            console.log('reg service '+ this.result);
        }

    });

}
```

[Error screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZR26.png)
Please help on this issue.

Comment: Obviously your "posts" variable is undefined. Check your RegEmp method to see why you're not getting any value.

Comment: this is regEMp method,

regEmp(EmpReg) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let body = JSON.stringify(EmpReg);
        console.log("service body  "+body);
        var result= this.http.post('http://localhost:9810/api/Values/Register', body, options )
        .map(res => res.json());
        return result;
      }
and this is returning value from the service.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `this` variables. You should do it like this:

```
ResgisterNewEmp(employeeCreds)
{
   var $this = this;
   $this._empRegistrationService.regEmp(employeeCreds).subscribe(posts=>{
     $this.result=posts;
     if($this.result =="201")
     {
        $this._router.navigate(['Signin']);
        console.log('reg service '+ $this.result);
     }

    });
}
```